# Not able to see the values of object?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

In the below code i have created object "**cart**" and i have assigned that "**cart**" object to "**addToCart**" variable but not able to see the assigned values of "**cart**" and "**addToCart**" variable in **addItemToCart()** method
so please tell me how to create object and assign values to it

And "let span  = this.template.querySelectorAll('span');" has
following values

```
span[0].innerText  // a005h00000nCm1uAAC
span[1].innerText  // Sticky Baked Chicken Wings
span[2].innerText  // 3 it is Number
```

**itemDetails.js**

```
import { LightningElement,api,wire } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe,MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import FOODITEM from '@salesforce/messageChannel/FoodItem__c'
export default class itemDetails extends LightningElement {
    
    Id;
    Name;
    Quantity = "3";
    subscription = null;

    addToCart ;

    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext
    
    connectedCallback(){
        this.subscribeToMessageChannel(); 
    }

    subscribeToMessageChannel(){
        this.subscription = subscribe(
            this.messageContext,
            FOODITEM,
            (message) => this.handleMessage(message)
            )
    }
    handleMessage(message){
        let values = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(message.dishName));
        this.Id = values.Id;
        this.Name = values.Name;
    }
    addItemToCart(){
    
        let span  = this.template.querySelectorAll('span');

        let cart  = {
                i : span[0].innerText,
                n : span[1].innerText,
                q : span[2].innerText
        }
    this.addToCart = cart;
    console.log("cart:-",cart);
    console.log("cart:-",this.addToCart);
    }
}
```

**itemDetails.html**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <lightning-formatted-rich-text></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
        <p>Id: <span>{Id}</span></p>
        <p>Name of the dish: <span>{Name}</span></p>
        <lightning-layout class="slds-m-top_x-small">
            <lightning-button title="add" icon-name="utility:add"></lightning-button>
            <p>Quantity <span>{Quantity}</span></p>
            <lightning-button title="remove" icon-name="utility:dash"></lightning-button>
        </lightning-layout>
        <lightning-button label="Add To Cart" onclick={addItemToCart}></lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What do you see if you use `console.log("cart:-",JSON.stringify(cart));`?

Comment: if i use `console.log(cart)`  it shows `proxy(object)` when it is empty but when i put some value in it It doesn't execute and type of empty object shows `object`

Comment: That is why you need to use e.g. `JSON.stringify` so the proxy is converted to actual data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you already have the data available within your component, I would avoid trying to get this data using a query selector and use it directly.

To construct the cart you should be able to do the following:

```
addItemToCart(){

    let cart  = {
            i : this.Id
            n : this.Name
            q : this.Quantity
    }
    
    this.addToCart = cart;
}
```